# Group and Get top(n) records by count times out in linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, iqueryable

I'm trying to get the top 10 most visited organisations using Linq and GroupBy. When an organisation is accessed their information is logged using the following class. There are up to 1000 records added per day.

```
public class LogOrgAccess
{
    public int OrganisationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccessDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganisationID")]
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

}
```

My Organisation class look like:

```
 public partial class Organisation
 {

    public int OrganisationID { get; set; }
    public string OrgName { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; } 
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
 }
```

I want to pull back the top (n) visited organisations within a timeframe so I've created a class to map the results to:

```
    public class OrgAccessDTO
    {
    public int OrganisationID { get; set; }
    public string OrgName { get; set; }

    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    }
```

I've written the following query to try and return the required data:

```
     public IQueryable<OrgAccessDTO> GetOrgAccessByDateRange(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
     {

        return _UoW.LogOrgAccess.All.Where(s => s.AccessDate >= fromDate && s.AccessDate <= toDate)
             .GroupBy(s => s.OrganisationID)
                    .Select(g => new OrgAccessDTO
                    {
                        OrganisationID = g.FirstOrDefault().OrganisationID,
                        OrgName = g.FirstOrDefault().Organisation.OrgName,
                        Latitude = g.FirstOrDefault().Organisation.Latitude,
                        Longitude = g.FirstOrDefault().Organisation.Longitude,
                        Counter = g.Count(),
                    }
              ).OrderByDescending(g=>g.Counter).Take(10);
    }
```

Im returning the Iqueryable to my controller like so:

```
IList<OrgAccessDTO> logs = _logService.GetOrgAccessByDateRange(start, end).ToList();
```

The query keeps timing out with the exception "Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out".

I've extended the timeout property on my connection but this does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: You should replace `g.FirstOrDefault().OrganisationID` with `g.Key`. Are you using EF or EF Core? Can you run the SQL generated - if you have a large amount of data and insufficient indexing, you could timeout.

Comment: @NetMage Thanks, Im using EF. I initially thought there was a problem with the query however I've added indexing to the table and albeit the query runs slow, it is now pulling out the required data.

Comment: I would still suggest looking at the SQL. It may be pulling data over to the client because the `Select` is before the `OrderBy`+`Take`. Something like `GroupBy().OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()),Take(10),Select()` may push more work to the SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought there may be an issue with the query itself, however after adding an index to the OrgAccess table in the database, the query is now pulling out the required data. Even though its still a little slow.

There also seems to be an issue with RAM on the development machine. (Its running at full capacity). When uploaded to the web server the query executes much faster.